# Unable to add data into database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created a 8 column table in SQL Server 2008. I entered data into 1st 2 column of the table and remaining columns I left allow nulls.

I am trying to add data to remaining 6 columns based on the data entered in 1st 2 columns, but I'm not able to add the data. Was leaving another 6 columns into "Allow nulls" caused this problem.

If yes, is there any solution for this?

Thanks.

```
string str = (@"Data Source=.\;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");

try
{
    String sql = "(insert into usn (firstname, lastname, password, address, bloodgrp, contactnum, email) values (@st1, @st2, @st3, @st4, @st5, @st6, @st7) WHERE usn = '" + omd + "' )";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st1", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st2", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st3", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st4", TextBox10.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st5", TextBox6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st6", TextBox7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st7", TextBox8.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("accountcreated.aspx");

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: How are you trying to add data? Can you show us your query .. or explain your method?

Comment: The 1st 2 columns of the data base includes regnum and name of the customer associated with regnum. The rest of the fields i am using to created account for those customer. So the regnum of specified users are already stored in 1st two columns. Based on this method i need to add data to remaining 6 fields.

Comment: The `INSERT` statement cannot have a `WHERE` clause ..... you want to **insert** that row - you cannot do that depending on a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I am using the following statement :

Comment: {String sql = "(UPDATE usn SET firstname = !st1, lastname = !st2, password = !st3, address = !st4, bloodgrp = !st5, contactnum = !st6, email = !st7 WHERE usn = '" + omd + "')";} But stil its not getting updated. please replace ! with @

Answer (score 0):

If you already have records in your table, you need to use `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`.

So, your query should be something like

```
UPDATE usn
SET firstname = @st1,
    lastname = @st2,
    password = @st3,
    address = @st4,
    bloodgrp = @st5,
    contactnum = @st6,
    email = @st7
WHERE usn = ...
```

You can't `INSERT` into a column, you use `INSERT` only to put data into a table (creating a record).

So, your sql String should look something like this.

```
String sql = "(UPDATE usn SET firstname = @st1, lastname = @st2, password = @st3, address = @st4, bloodgrp = @st5, contactnum = @st6, email = @st7 WHERE usn = '" + omd + "' )";
```

Comment: Sir, I tried this. But its not working yet. Is setting other columns into allow nulls while creating the table caused this problem. Its not showing any errors and the page is not navigating to next one when it has to once the data gets updated into table. The WHERE condition i am checking (omd) contains string value and usn contains varchar. Is this may be the problem?